# Optical flow using opencv

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am using Pyramid Lukas Kanade function of OpenCV to estimate the optical flow. i call the `cvGoodFeaturesToTrack` and then `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. This is my code:

```
while(1)
{
...

cvGoodFeaturesToTrack(frameAth,eig_image,tmp_image,cornersA,&corner_count,0.01,5,NULL,3,0.4);

std::cout<<"CORNER COUNT AFTER GOOD FEATURES2TRACK CALL = "<<corner_count<<std::endl;

cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK(frameAth,frameBth,pyrA,pyrB,cornersA,cornersB,corner_count,cvSize(win_size,win_size),5,features_found,features_errors,cvTermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_ITER| CV_TERMCRIT_EPS,20,0.3 ),CV_LKFLOW_PYR_A_READY|CV_LKFLOW_PYR_B_READY);

cvCopy(frameBth,frameAth,0);
...
}
```

`frameAth` is the previous gray frame and `frameBth` is the current gray frame from a webcam. But when i output the number of good features to track in each frame the number decreases after sum time and keeps decreasing. but if i terminate the program and execute the code again(without disturbing the field of view of the webcam ) a lot more number of points are shown as good features to track...how can for the same field of view and for the same scene the function give such difference in number of points...and the difference is high..eg..number of points as good features to track after 4 minutes of execution is 20 or 50...but when the same program terminated and executed again the number is 500 to 700 initialy but again slowly decreases..i am using opencv for the past 4 months so i am lil new to openCV..please guide me or tell me where i can find a solution...lots of thanx in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `cvGoodFeatureToTrack` and passing `corner_count` by reference. Its value decreases if less features are found. You have to reset the value of `corner_count` to its initial value before calling `cvGoodFeaturesToTrack`in each iteration of while loop.

Comment: @sgar91...thanx...i had an improvement in the performance by your suggestion

Comment: i experienced the same issue a while ago.

Comment: @rotating_image I don't understand why this answer checked as accepted. When you reset number of features than it makes no sense to call `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK` at all. It will give you the same result when you don't call it... Read docs first.

Answer (score 6):

You have to call `cvGoodFeaturesToTrack` once (at the beginning, before loop) to detect good features to track and than track these features using `cvCalcOpticalFlowPyrLK`. Take a look at default opencv example: `OpenCV/samples/cpp/lkdemo.cpp`.

Comment: @Astor...thanx Astor for a quick response...the process you said works fine to track a moving object in the field of view...however i am using optical flow to estimate camera motion..so when a camera is moving its field of view is changing...the scene details are also changing slowly...so if i call goodfeaturestotrack once then when the scene is changing slowly i am not getting new points coz the initial points might not be present in the new frame...

Comment: @user1466741 To detect camera motion you can use motion detection using [frame subtraction](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KREoXEy9ojY). This algorithm is very easy - you have to substract two consistent frames, do threshold and check if area of motion (white pixels on video) is big (80% of full area or something) then camera is moving. However this algorithm is bad when illumanion is changing (turn lights on/off) or when someone (or something) is moving very close to camera.

Comment: @Astor...thanx for the idea but with optical flow i can get the direction and the magnitude of the movement easily...will calling goodfeaturestotrack function periodicaly (after certain number of frames or when the number of goodpoints2track go down ) solve the problem?i mean if i keep refreshing the points to track...

Comment: @user1466741 only you can answer such question - just try it with your environment and if result is acceptable for you than yes, such method is good for you. Actually I don't know other methods to detect camera motion - read some articles and maybe you will get good answer. Good luck!